# nice and ionice: which one should come first?

Tags: btrfs, nice, ionice

I need to run some long and heavy commands, but at the same time, I'd like to keep my desktop system responsive.

Examples: btrfs deduplication, btrfs balance, etc. I don't mind if such commands take longer to finish if I give them a lower priority, but my system should always be responsive.

Using `nice -n 19` and `ionice -c 3` should solve my problem, but I'm not sure which command should come first for maximum benefit.

- Option A:

  ```bash
  nice -n 19 ionice -c 3 btrfs balance start --full-balance /
  ```
- Option B:

  ```bash
  ionice -c 3 nice -n 19 btrfs balance start --full-balance /
  ```

Is there some subtle difference between options A and B? Are they equivalent perhaps?

Comment: It would only make a difference if `ionice` were very computational, or `nice` did lots of I/O. Neither is true.

Comment: @Barmar: If you create an answer based on your comment I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If `nice` caused lots of I/O, you would want to do:

```
ionice -c 3 nice ...
```

so that the impact of the I/O would be minimized.

Conversely, if `ionice` performed lots of computation, you would want to do

```
nice -n 19 ionice ...
```

to minimize its CPU impact.

But neither of these is true, they're both very simple commands (they just make a system call to change a process parameter, then execute the command). So the difference should be negligible.

And just to be complete, if both were true, you can't really win -- the impact of one of them can't be reduced.

Comment: So what you are saying is in the case of `nice -n 19 ionice ...` nice modifies the priority of ionice; and in the case of `ionice -c 3 nice ...` ionice modifies the priority of nice. And in neither case do both commands modify the priorities of  `btrfs balance ...`.  I believe the desire is to have both commands affect the niceness of `btrfs balance ...`.

Comment: @TiberiusKirk The priorities are inherited, so `btrfs balance` gets both priority adjustments. I was only addressing the difference between the order of the two adjustment commands.

Comment: I just read somewhere that nice will also change the IO priority. Does that change this answer in any way?

Comment: @Nabheet I haven't found that in any of the online man pages. Can you find a reference that confirms that?

Comment: The man page for ionice implies that the default io priority is `io_priority = (cpu_nice + 20) / 5`. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153636/134331. https://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice. I guess maybe `nice` doesn't change the IO priority, maybe the IO priority automatically changes based on CPU priority?

Comment: That's only the relative priority within the Best Effort I/O priority class.

Comment: @Nabheet You still have to use `ionice` to select the I/O class.

Answer (score 9):

There is no practical difference between option A and option B.